# Analytic branch of log z in O shaped region.

Tags: complex-analysis

If I take a region 3<|z|<5, can I define an analytic branch of log there? Why can I not define an analytic branch?

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be done, because still $\log'(z)=\frac1z$ and, for $\gamma(t)=4e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ $$\oint_\gamma \frac1z\,dz\ne0$$

Comment: Why is that integral not 0? z=0 is not in the set.

Comment: @StackBlueEye The reason why it isn't $0$ is that it's $2i\pi$. As for $0$ not being in the set, $0$ is never "in the set".